# Rubocop – how can I just display auto-correctable results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I would like to run Rubocop and just see auto-correctable results. The documentation (https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/usage/basic_usage.html) indicates this should be possible with a `--display-only-correctable` flag.

But at the command line `rubocop --display-only-correctable`
responds:

> invalid option: --display-only-correctable
> Did you mean?  display-only-failed
> For usage information, use –help

And from `rubocop --help` I don’t see any reference to the display-only-correctable flag.
Is it possible to just just display auto-correctable results?
Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Which version of RuboCop are you using? That option was added fairly recently in 1.28.0: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1280-2022-04-21

Comment: Spot on, thanks! I was on 1.25.1. Updating solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andy Waite’s comment helped solve it.
I was running rubocop version 1.25.1.  The `--display-only-correctable` flag only arrived arrived in version 1.28.0.
I changed my gemfile from:

```
gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.25', require: false
```

to

```
gem 'rubocop', require: false
```

then ran

```
bundle update
```

now `rubocop --display-only-correctable` works as expected.